# Regex pattern for Datetime format using R

Tags: r, excel

I have column A in a data frame(30k rows and 11 columns) with multiple strings and DateTime as inputs. I need to retrieve all rows if it has value in the below DateTime format

2020-08-31 23:45:17

Can someone suggest the exact regex pattern for the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way to retrieve all rows where column A contains the desired pattern

```
df <- data.frame(A = c("bla", "2020-08-31 23:45:17", "bla"),
                 B = 1:3)

df[grepl(df$A, pattern = "\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2} \\d{2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}"),]
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider a function like this

```
is_datetime <- function(x, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS") {
  !is.na(as.POSIXct(x, format = format, optional = TRUE))
}
```

Then, you can just

```
> is_datetime(c("apple", "2020-08-31", "2020-08-31 23:45:17"))
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

Assume that you have a dataframe `df` with column `A` that contains some date-time characters. Then,

```
df[is_datetime(df$A), ]
```

should get you the rows you want. I haven't tested this because you did not include any sample data in your question, but it should work.